# Understand this filter and biasing circuit

Tags: filter, bias, coupling, high-pass-filter

[image: High pass filter circuit with bias.]

Hello

I don't have much experience with electronics and I am trying to understand how this circuit works and its effect on AC input signals.

My understanding so far is that the circuit acts as a high pass filter. But I am not sure of the effect of changing the resistor values (different for both resistors).

Thank you

Comment: Brendan Simpson's answer below explains the DC bias part well, but I want to point out: while there is nothing wrong with the circuit the way it is, the two resistors can be replaced with a single 41kΩ resistor to ground. Either way, the cutoff frequency is ~39Hz and the DC bias point is 0V.

Answer (score 3):

In a great simplification, ignoring cutoff frequencies and reactance, C can be treated as a short circuit to AC signals and an Open circuit to DC signals. This *AC-couples* the input node, Vi, to the output node, Vo. In effect, this removes any DC component from the input (when observed from Vo's point of view).

The resistors form a simple biasing network, which creates a voltage divider between the +2.5V rail and the -2.5V rail. Since both Rs have the same resistance value, the DC voltage at node Vo will be 0V, as long as no signal is applied to Vin. When a signal is applied to Vin, the signal at Vout will be centered around the DC bias of 0V.

What does this all mean for you? Well you could change the resistor values to change the DC bias. For example, in a system where you wanted to be able to measure AC signals with some sort of receiver (ADC, input amplifier, etc.), but you didn't have a negative rail, you might set the bias at half of the supply voltage. That way, even if Vin was going from +1V to -1V, you could still read it on your input.

Keep in mind, if you start mucking with the resistor values, your cutoff frequency will change. So, the best solution is to keep your cutoff freqency far enough below your operating band that way it doesn't really matter[1] anymore what the cutoff frequency is.

[1] "doesn't really matter": For example, if you are trying to pass audio, just make sure your cutoff frequency is a couple orders of magnitude below your lowest expected audio frequency, then it won't matter what the attenuation looks like, since there will be almost no attenuation at the low end of your input range.

Answer (score 2):

Simplified analysis is that the capacitor is a low impedance to high frequencies, high impedance to low frequencies and open circuit to DC.

This basic hand waving should convince you that the average voltage out is 0V and that this is an high pass filter.

Lets now apply a more rigorous analysis so we can put some numbers to the performance.

If we ignore the capacitor now we can remove it and replace the two resistors with a Thevenin equivalent circuit.  To do this we replace the circuit with a voltage source equal to the voltage seen at the junction of the a resistors, 0V, together with with an impedance equal to that you would see if you replaced the voltage sources with short circuits.  If we had any current sources we would replace these with open circuits.  In this case the impedance is \$41\text{ k}\Omega\$

Putting the capacitor back into this equivalent circuit we have.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fofQjD.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Now we can easily see this is an is a high pass filter with gain

\$ A = \dfrac{Rth}{Rth + \dfrac{1}{j \cdot \omega \cdot C1 }} = \dfrac{Rth}{1 + j \cdot \omega \cdot C \cdot Rth}\$

This is a simple high pass filter with corner frequency.

\$ \omega = \dfrac{1}{C \cdot Rth} \$, \$ f = \dfrac{1}{2 \dot \pi \cdot C \cdot Rth} \approx 38.8 Hz \$

Comment: So what does this mean? Can he remove R1 and replace R2 with \$41 k \Omega \$? And if you do, it doubles the \$f_c\$, then why do people design the circuits as shown in OP? (I.e. why not remove R1 right away?)

Comment: Having two identical resistors gives a DC output half way between the supply rails.  If these are equal and opposite (as drawn) then this is 0V and you could remove R1 and replace R2 with 41k to 0V.  This does not double \$ f_c \$ since from AC point of view R1 and R2 are in parallel. Just imagine an infinite capacitor across the supply rails to understand why.  Perhaps the designer wanted to ensure the average (DC) output was halfway between the rails even if they were not equal and opposite.